# signal: segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, printf

Wrote a program that multiply two arrays like this:

**u*v = u1*v1 + u2*v2 + u3*v3 + ... un*vn**

after getting from the user both of the arrays, i get a "signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int scalar_product(int vectorU[], int vectorV[], int vectorLength) {
  int i, sum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < vectorLength; i++)
    sum += (vectorU[i] * vectorV[i]);
  return sum;
}

void userInterface() {
  int vectorLength = 0, i;
  printf("Please enter the length of the vectors: ");
  scanf("%d", &vectorLength);
  int vectorU[vectorLength], vectorV[vectorLength];
  printf("\nVector U:");
  for (i = 0; i < vectorLength; i++) {
    printf("\n%d) ", (i + 1));
    scanf("%d", &vectorU[i]);
  }
  printf("\nVector V:");
  for (i = 0; i < vectorLength; i++) {
    printf("\n%d) ", (i + 1));
    scanf("%d", &vectorV[i]);
  }
  printf(scalar_product(vectorU, vectorV, vectorLength));
}

main(void) {
  userInterface();
}
```

Comment: Always enable and heed your compiler's warnings. (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with `gcc`) The problem would have been identified.

Comment: As an aside, `main(void) { ... }` should be `int main(void) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call of printf is incorrect

```
printf(scalar_product(vectorU, vectorV, vectorLength));
```

You need to write at least

```
printf( "%d\n", scalar_product(vectorU, vectorV, vectorLength));
```

Also it would be better to declare and define the function like

```
long long int scalar_product( const int vectorU[], const int vectorV[], int vectorLength) {
  long long int sum = 0;
  for ( int i = 0; i < vectorLength; i++)
    sum += ( long long int )vectorU[i] * vectorV[i];
  return sum;
}
```

To output the result you need to use the format string `"%lld\n"`..

The type `long long int` is used to avoid an overflow.

Another way is to declare the function return type as `double`.

Also you forgot to specify the return type `int` of the function main.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

> ```
>   printf(scalar_product(vectorU, vectorV, vectorLength));
> ```

... you have failed to specify a format for `printf`.  As a result, it attempts to interpret the result of `scalar_product()` as a pointer to the format string.  Undefined behavior results.

If your compiler is not emitting a warning about that then you should either learn how to turn up the warning level so that it does, or else get a better compiler.  If your compiler *is* emitting a warning about it, then take this as a lesson that it is not safe to ignore compiler warnings.

Probably you wanted somethign more like this:

```
  printf("%d\n", scalar_product(vectorU, vectorV, vectorLength));
```

---

As a minor additional issue, you have forgotten the return type for `main()`.  Your compiler is probably treating it as returning `int`, which turns out to be the right thing to do, but that doesn't make your code correct.  You want:

```
int main(void) {
    // ...
```

---

With those two changes, your program compiles for me without any diagnostics, and runs without error, producing the result I expect.

At least, for small vector lengths.  If you try really large vectors then you might exceed the available space for allocating your vectors on the stack.